# GridLayout dynamically change to fill Gone view

Tags: android, kotlin, grid, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I am using a GridLayout to design a dashboard which a 2 columns based one. So I am just adding widgets and it directly define the Grid.

The issue I have is that, I have 12 cells but some will be set as `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE` depending on the information availability. The issue I have is that when the cell is set to `View.GONE`, it not showing but the space is still there.

I was hoping that when I set a cell to `View.GONE`, the next cell set to `View.VISIBLE` will show up and not let an empty cell in the middle of my screen.

[image]

Sorry I can't post an image of my screen, So I tried to make one. above is what I see. I was expecting that when a cell is set to `View.GONE`, the cells re-arrange themselves and no empty cells will show up

The xml I am using is :

```
<GridLayout
                    android:id="@+id/grid"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:columnCount="2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        layout="@layout/button_a"
                        bind:tileModel="@{model.button1}"/>

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        layout="@layout/button_b"
                        bind:tileModel="@{model.button2}"/>

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        layout="@layout/button_a"
                        bind:tileModel="@{model.button3}"/>

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        layout="@layout/button_c"
                        bind:tileModel="@{model.button4}"/>

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        layout="@layout/button_b"
                        bind:tileModel="@{model.button5}"/>

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/button6"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        layout="@layout/button_a"
                        bind:tileModel="@{model.button6}"/>
```

the `tileModel` receive the viewModel and pass the information to the associated layout.

Any idea ?

Comment: If your data is dynamic, build the layout the same way. Check what information is required (via the ViewModel) then add the relevant children in the gridview.

Comment: @DarShan So mostly doing a programmatical way, where I just add what I need instead of trying to make them Visible/Gone

Comment: No, I meant only `add` views to GridView that you need as per your data.

Comment: @DarShan yes but the `add` is done through the code. the XML should not contain any items, just the GridLayout and I use grid.add() in the code

Comment: I suggest using a RecyclerView with GridLayout and a ListAdapter with DiffUtil. You can add and remove items from a backing list of items, and it will animate the changes for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE, because View.INVISIBLE hide only  the view not it's space, whereas View.GONE hide view as well as space occupied by it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to use this custom RearrangingGridLayout because default gridlayout do not have expected behaviour.
2. use this class in XML layout.
3. onCreate of your Activity just use saveViews() method initially.

class you will have to use:

```
public class RearrangingGridLayout extends GridLayout { 
private final List views = new ArrayList<>();

public RearrangingGridLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public RearrangingGridLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public RearrangingGridLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

private void arrangeElements() {
    removeAllViews();

    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
        if (views.get(i).getVisibility() != GONE)
            addView(views.get(i));
    }
}

public void saveViews() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        views.add(getChildAt(i));
    }
}

public void hideView(View child) {
    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
        if (views.get(i).getId() == child.getId()) {
            views.get(i).setVisibility(GONE);
            arrangeElements();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void showView(View child) {
    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
        if (views.get(i).getId() == child.getId()) {
            views.get(i).setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            arrangeElements();
        }
    }
}}
```

onCreate:

```
glRearranging.saveViews();
```

hide view like this,

```
glRearranging.hideView(viewName);
```

show view like this,

```
glRearranging.showView(viewName);
```